# Start over with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I start over with Visual Studio Code on macOS Mojave? A program delete and reinstall from a download manages to preserve many preference settings that I would like **not** to have.

TIA,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Found it by searching their docs for "uninstall". At the very bottom, there is a FAQ showing a couple of directories that need to be deleted before reinstalling.